# get selectors by property js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a css file, where I place all my styles by page.

How I can get the selectors' class/id by searching for a property in css.

For example, I want to change the text color by all pages. I need to get an array with all the selectors that have a property of "color".

How I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: it's not a bad question, and not only because I have a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

so fun, i have answered a similar question (but for another problem). :)

=> see = https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

```js
let myGroup = document.querySelector('#my-Group');

let myGroupCSS = getComputedStyle(myGroup);

Bt_change_Color.onclick = function () {

    let current_Color = myGroupCSS.getPropertyValue('--color_for_group');

    console.log('first color', current_Color);  //  #305395

    myGroup.style.setProperty('--color_for_group', '#95305a');
}
```

```css
#my-Group {
  --color_for_group: #305395;
}
h2 {
  color: var(--color_for_group);
}
h4{
  color: var(--color_for_group);
}
p {
  color: var(--color_for_group);
}
```

```html
<div id="my-Group">
    <h2>title</h2>

    <h4>sub tilte</h4>

    <p>paragraph</p>
</div>

<button id="Bt_change_Color"> Change Color </button>
```